# Jquery + Ajax, Params has data but response says no data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have the following script:

```
$("#spid").blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'getsponsor.php',
       type: "POST",
       dataType:'json',
       data: ({ spid: $("#spid").val() }) ,
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       success: function (result) {
           $("#sponname").text(result);
       },
       error: function () {
           $("#sponname").text("Cannot fetch the sponsor name.");
       }
   }); 
});
```

> Note: #sponname is a label tag.

Following is the php code of getsponsor.php:

```
if(!isset($_POST['spid']) || empty($_POST['spid']))
    echo json_encode("No Data");
else {
    $spid=$_POST['spid'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$spid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows >0) {
        $row = $stmt->fetch_object();
        echo json_encode($row->name);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode("No Records");
    }
}
```

When I Inspect the page and goto **Network->Params**, I get the right value from the textbox:

> spid=1125468

But, when I go to **Network->Response**, I get the following message

> "No Data"

Please tell what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Don't use `contentType: "application/json"`. jQuery URL-encodes the parameters.

Comment: You don't need to test both `!isset` and `empty`. `empty` checks whether it's set first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of this line:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

The data is being sent URL-encoded, not as JSON. jQuery will send the correct Content-type header by itself.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfect. But, when we have mentioned application/json, why it sends as url-encoded. Please explain.

Comment: If you use an object as the `data:` parameter, it's always URL-encoded. It doesn't care about `contentType`. PHP also doesn't know how to parse JSON post data, it only understands URL-encoded and multipart/form-data.